# Macro needs cleaned up

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook I have been working on.  This workbook has 3 sheets of information that help populate a MASTER sheet through excel index and match functions as well as other functions.  The A2 cell on the MASTER sheet is a drop down box of names. As each name is chosen a macro linked to a button helps summarize the information and then an other button copies and paste the sheet to a new sheet in the workbook. My question is on the macro that summarizes the information. Being new to macros, I put this together with information gathered on the Internet.  I noticed that it is hiding some rows when used which is not good and works really slow. Also, not of great important, it places the paste anywhere within the range. Even sometimes lines apart, like on E14 and E16 instead of E14 and E15. I am sure there is a better way of writing this macro and any help and education would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub UniqueValues()

Dim ws As Worksheet

'list states for install & service

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheets("MASTER")
ws.Range("D94:D144").AdvancedFilter Action:=x1FilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Range("D94:D144").Copy
ws.Range("E14:E19").PasteSpecial x1Values
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'list states for overrides

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheets("MASTER")
ws.Range("D147:D246")AdvancedFilter Action:=x1FilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Range("D147:D246").Copy
ws.Range("E21:E26").PasteSpecial x1Values
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'lists states for licenses

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheets("MASTER")
ws.Range("D249:D298").AdvancedFilter Action:=x1FilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Range("D249:D298").Copy
ws.Range("E35:E38").PasteSpecial x1Values
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'lists states for commissions

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheets("MASTER")
ws.Range("D301:D327").AdvancedFilter Action:=x1FilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Range("D301:D327").Copy
ws.Range("E28:E33").PasteSpecial x1Values
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'In Place' filter + copy paste will be very slow. If you want to improve your code you could use a Dictionary (available in the Microsoft Scripting Runtime)

```
Sub getUniquesValues(output As Range, cells As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim knownValues As New Dictionary

    For Each cell In cells
        If Not knownValues.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            output = cell.Value
            Set output = output.Offset(1, 0)
            knownValues.Add cell.Value, 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then all you have to do is call the sub this way :

```
Sub ImprovedUniqueValues()
    Dim cell As Range, output As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("MASTER")
    Set output = ws.Range("E19")

    getUniquesValues output, ws.Range("D94", ws.Range("D94").End(xlDown))
    ....
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I tried your subs on a test and could not get past the first sub.  It gave me a user-defined type not defined error on Dim knownValues As New Dictionary, so I am sure I am not doing something right.  Also, if I understand code which is very little, as I am just learning, your .End(x1Down))stops at a blank?  Which is not a problem with 3 of the ranges, but the range ("D94:D144") has a blank area in between.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' library.

Comment: I added the ".End(xlDown)" as a suggestion, maybe in your case you may have to call the function with an explicit range or by using a 'named range' .  Best regards

Comment: I had to find the reference dialog box. The whole sub works best for me with the explicit ranges, but it is fantastic. Thank you very much for the education.  Now to figure out how to give you credit for the great answer by voting.